# LaTeX - long table problem

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a problem with my long tables in LaTeX, especially multirow cells. It makes 'ugly edges' - the table continues under the number of pages. Thanks very much for any advice!

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\newcommand{\B}{\textbf} % tučné písmo
\newcommand{\It}{\textit} % kurzíva

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{graphicx} % balíček pro grafiku
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[total={16cm,24 cm}, top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{changepage,threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    {\Large \B{STŘEDOŠKOLSKÁ ODBORNÁ ČINNOST}} \\
        \vspace{5mm}
        \large \B{Obor č. 4: Biologie}\\
        \vspace{70mm}
        {\huge \B{Název práce}} \\
        \vspace{5mm}
        {\LARGE \B{Přílohy}} \\
        \vfill
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}
    {\Large \B{Adriena Jedličková}} \\
    \vspace{2,5mm}
    {\Large \B{Jihomoravský kraj}} \hfill {\Large \bfseries Brno a rok}
\end{flushleft}

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\section{Podrobné kvantifikované výsledky}
\subsection{Nerozpustná forma olova}
\subsection{Rozpustná forma olova}
\subsubsection{Plíce}
\paragraph{CD68} 
Z každého z každého byly obarveny čtyři řezy. Následně bylo z každého řezu pořízeno 10 fotografií, ve kterých byly kvantifikovány nalezené pozitivní buňky (viz tabulky  -- ). Statistická významnost výsledků byla ověřena pomocí Studentova t-testu.

\shorthandoff{-}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Podrobné kvantifikované výsledky CD68 v plicích: kontrolní skupina}
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{ K } \\\hline
        označení sklíčka & číslo řezu & číslo fotky & počet pozitivních buněk & průměr_řez & průměr_sklíčko \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 36  K  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 8 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 5,8 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 7,625 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 2 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 6 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 9 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,3 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 9 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 6 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 7,5 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 4 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4} 
        & & 5 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 37  K  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 8 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 7,4 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 7,2 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 5 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 7,6 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 22 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 6 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 6,4 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 6 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 7,4 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 38  K  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 4,5 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 6,175 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 1 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 1 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 6 & & \\\cline{2-54}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 7,4 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 8 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 4 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 6,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 7 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 8 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 5,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 2 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 39  K  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 11 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,3 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 9,875 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 6 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,6 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 15 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,1 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 10 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,5 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 12 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 40  K  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 11 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,9 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 9,025 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 8 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 6 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,6 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 7 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 9 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,3 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 12 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,3 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 4 & & \\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\shorthandon{-}

\shorthandoff{-}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Podrobné kvantifikované výsledky CD68 v plicích: experimentální skupina č. 1}
         \hline
         \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Pb} \\\hline
         označení sklíčka & číslo řezu & číslo fotky & pozitivní buňky & průměr řez & průměr sklíčko \\ \hline
         \multirow{39}{*}{36 Pb 11t} & \multirow{10}{*}{1 1} & 1 & 12 & \multirow{10}{*}{18,2} & \multirow{39}{*}{17,1} \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 2 & 30 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 3 & 11 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 4 & 19 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 5 & 15 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 6 & 33 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 7 & 15 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 8 & 18 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 9 & 14 & \\ \cline{3-4}
         & & 10 & 15 & \\ \cline{2-5}
         & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 6 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 14,6 } & \\\cline{3-4} 
        & & 2 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 27 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
           & & 10 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 16,7 } & \\\cline{2-5}
        & & 2 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 27 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 18 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 17,1 } & \\\cline{2-5}
        & & 2 & 21 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 20 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 18 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 37  Pb  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 12 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,8 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 11,325 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 14 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,4 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 16 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 15 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 11 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,1 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 7 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 38  Pb  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 21 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 13,1 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 12,95 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 20 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 9 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 15 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 13,2 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 13 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 14 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 21 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 8 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 19 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 13,6 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 20 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 12 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 39  Pb  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 17,7 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 16 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 31 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 22 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 20 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 15 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 18 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,5 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 8 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 11 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 13,7 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 28 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 12 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 9 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 16 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 22 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 20 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 25 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 24 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 24 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 40  Pb  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,9 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 12 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 6 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 12 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 13,5 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 11 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 12,7 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 21 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 13 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 13 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 11,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\shorthandon{-}

\newpage
\shorthandoff{-}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Podrobné kvantifikované výsledky CD68 v plicích: experimentální skupina č. 2}
    \label{CD68_PbS_CL} \\

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{ Pb  CL } \\\hline
        označení sklíčka & číslo řezu & číslo fotky & počet pozitivních buněk & průměr  řez & průměr  sklíčko \\\hline

        \multirow{40}{*}{ 6  PbS  CL  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 10 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,8 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 8,95 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10,1 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 5 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,1 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 11 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 5 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 7,8 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 7  PbS  CL  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 9 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,5 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 9,325 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 8 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 6 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,7 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 11 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 9 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,1 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 6 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 8 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 8  PbS  CL  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 22 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 8,85 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 4 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 8 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,1 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 8 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 8,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 3 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 11 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 11 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,4 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 6 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 9  PbS  CL  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 10 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10,3 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 10,4 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 17 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 8 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 9 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10,7 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 18 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 14 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 15 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,8 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 4 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 17 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10,8 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 11 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 15 & & \\\hline
        \multirow{40}{*}{ 10  PbS  CL  11t } & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  1 } & 1 & 7 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10,1 } & \multirow{40}{*}{ 10,65 } \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 16 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 15 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 5 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 1  2 } & 1 & 8 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 12,6 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 7 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 21 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}\
        & & 10 & 19 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  1 } & 1 & 10 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 10 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 14 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 10 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 12 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 10 & & \\\cline{2-5}
        & \multirow{10}{*}{ 2  2 } & 1 & 10 & \multirow{10}{*}{ 9,9 } & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 2 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 3 & 6 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 4 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 5 & 9 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 6 & 8 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 7 & 19 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 8 & 13 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 9 & 5 & & \\\cline{3-4}
        & & 10 & 7 & & \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\shorthandon{-}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pagebreaks in longtables generally don't work too well with multirow cells. Better aviod that combination by trying to redegign the table.

Comment: multirow really isn't doing anything here you can omit it and just leave the text in the first of the cells leaving the ones below empty.